# Restart cumsum in Pandas with condition

Tags: pandas, cumsum

I have columns amount & assets. Column target should be the cumsum of amount, but the sum should be reset to the current amount if the *previous* assets was equal to zero.

Sample:

```py
+--------+--------+--------+
| amount | assets | target |
+--------+--------+--------+
|      6 |     10 |      6 |
|      8 |     20 |     14 |
|     -1 |      0 |     13 |
|      6 |      1 |      6 |
|     -7 |      0 |     -1 |
|      2 |      4 |      2 |
|     -5 |      7 |     -3 |
|      3 |      9 |      0 |
|      7 |      0 |      7 |
|      9 |      2 |      9 |
|      1 |      3 |     10 |
|     -4 |      5 |      6 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) with groups created by compare column by `0` with shifting [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), processing first `NaN` and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
g = df['assets'].eq(0).shift().bfill().cumsum()
#alternative
#g = df['assets'].eq(0).shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
df['new'] = df.groupby(g)['amount'].cumsum()

print (df)
    amount  assets  target  new
0        6      10       6    6
1        8      20      14   14
2       -1       0      13   13
3        6       1       6    6
4       -7       0      -1   -1
5        2       4       2    2
6       -5       7      -3   -3
7        3       9       0    0
8        7       0       7    7
9        9       2       9    9
10       1       3      10   10
11      -4       5       6    6
```